# how to apply css to button field?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this ButtonField in grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mydatagrid"
PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows"
AllowPaging="True">
<Columns>
    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Update" HeaderText="Approve" ShowHeader="True"
        Text="Approve" />
</Columns>
<HeaderStyle CssClass="header"></HeaderStyle>
<PagerStyle CssClass="pager"></PagerStyle>
<RowStyle CssClass="rows"></RowStyle>
```

and i want apply this css on it

```
.simpleshape1
{
     //css
}
```

so how i can apply this css to this button

Answer (score 0):

Apply these properties

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
              runat="server"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CssClass="mydatagrid simpleshape1"
              PagerStyle-CssClass="pager"
              HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"
              RowStyle-CssClass="rows"
              AllowPaging="True">
```

Answer (score 0):

add this `class` to `ButtonField` tag:

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Update" HeaderText="Approve" ShowHeader="True" CssClass="simpleshape1"
    Text="Approve" />
```